# Launching Foursquare app in iOS7

Tags: ios7, foursquare

I am trying to launch the native Foursquare app in iOS7 via the root url scheme:
    `#define FOURSQUARE_URL_SCHEME @"foursquare://"`

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FOURSQUARE_URL_SCHEME]]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FOURSQUARE_URL_SCHEME]];
}
```

This launches Foursquare, but it doesn't completely load.  A blank view is displayed.
If I change the scheme to one of the four support schemes in the [client docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client), the app loads fine:
    `#define FOURSQUARE_URL_SCHEME @"foursquare://venues/4ab7e57cf964a5205f7b20e3"`

This only occurs when a user has previously logged into Foursquare.  If attempting on a fresh install, the Foursquare login view successfully displays.

Am I missing something, or is the root scheme no longer supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS dev @ Foursquare here. While we don't really document support for launching the app without any arguments, we designed the URL handling system to essentially do nothing in response to invalid or no arguments.

Unfortunately, you've hit a regression in our app that causes a modal to open anyway, so this isn't going to work for the time being. It'll soon be fixed in a future version of the app.

If there's something more specific that you're trying to accomplish, feel free to reply to this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response. All I am looking to do is launch Foursquare. I'll give it some thought and see if there is something else we can do to bring users into your app without a specific venue, checkin, tip, or user

Comment: Looks like the issue with the blank modal was fixed.  Thanks a lot!